# not able to concatenate two dataframes by multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting NA values when tried to merge two dataframes by common columns; I think it is straightforward to merge two dataframe by using `pandas.merge` and I should expect correct output; but I am not getting correct output. Here is what I did:

**my current attempt**:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/test_rl/main/df1.csv", index_col=0)
df2=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/test_rl/main/df2.csv", index_col=0)

merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['ST', 'County_Name'], right_on=['ST', 'County_Name'])
```

by doing so, I want to match `County_Name`, `ST` so merge them by `left` join and having `FIPS_Code` column as well; but now `FIPS_Code` become `NAN`, I am sure `County_Name` from `df1` can match in `df2`; I did manually checked but I don't get it why `FIPS_Code` become `NAN`; I want it `left` join because I want `merged_dataframe` has same shape as `df1`.

Can anyone point me out what went wrong with above join? Is that because of data or joining is not working here? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is space in your df2 `County_Name` column

[image]

```py
df2['County_Name'] = df2['County_Name'].str.strip()

merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['ST', 'County_Name'], right_on=['ST', 'County_Name'])
```

```
print(merged_df)

     ST County_Name Orientation   state_x  Year   state_y  FIPS_Code
0    IL       Adams     Defense  Illinois  2015  Illinois    17001.0
1    IL   Alexander     Defense  Illinois  2015  Illinois    17003.0
2    IL        Bond     Defense  Illinois  2015  Illinois    17005.0
3    IL       Boone     Defense  Illinois  2015  Illinois    17007.0
4    IL       Brown     Defense  Illinois  2015  Illinois    17009.0
..   ..         ...         ...       ...   ...       ...        ...
97   IL   Whiteside     Defense  Illinois  2015  Illinois    17195.0
98   IL        Will     Neutral  Illinois  2015  Illinois    17197.0
99   IL  Williamson     Defense  Illinois  2015  Illinois    17199.0
100  IL   Winnebago     Defense  Illinois  2015  Illinois    17201.0
101  IL    Woodford     Defense  Illinois  2015  Illinois    17203.0
```

Comment: Yep, I first suspected this might be the issue when I did `any(df1['County_Name'].isin(df2['County_Name']))` and got `False`.